# Get Android Unix Epoch 30 Minutes Before Now?

Tags: java, android, epoch

I understand that you can get the Unix Epoch in milliseconds in an android application using the following code:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

How would you therefore get the value 30 minutes before?

Comment: just subtract 30 minutes from it, `30*60*1000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using mathematics. There are 1000 milliseconds in a second, 60 seconds in a minute. Therefore:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() - 30 * 60 * 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

With `java.time`, the modern date-time API, you can do it without performing any calculations yourself.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long millisNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Instant instantNow = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisNow);
        Instant instant30MinsAgo = instantNow.minus(30, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        long millis30MinsAgo = instant30MinsAgo.toEpochMilli();
        // System.out.println(millis30MinsAgo);

        // In a single command
        long millisThrityMinsAgo = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                    .minus(30, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .toEpochMilli();
        
        // System.out.println(millisThrityMinsAgo);
    }
}
```

With the following code, you can get the current instant without using `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```
Instant.now()
```

Thus, you can get the Unix Epoch milliseconds 30 minutes ago with the following code also:

```
Instant.now().minus(30, ChronoUnit.MINUTES).toEpochMilli()
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>